# Strong typing of nullptr?

Tags: types, c++11, nullptr

I just read an article on the C++0x standard: http://www.softwarequalityconnection.com/2011/06/the-biggest-changes-in-c11-and-why-you-should-care/

It said `nullptr` was strongly typed, meaning that it can be distinguished from an integer 0.

```
f(int);
f(char* p);

f(nullptr); // calls char* version
```

That's all good, but I'm interesting in knowing what the standard says about `nullptr` with two pointer functions:

```
f(char* p);
f(int* p);

f(nullptr);
```

Do I need a cast here?  And is `nullptr` templated?

```
f((int*)(nullptr);
f(static_cast<int*>(nullptr));
f(nullptr<int>);               // I would prefer this
```

Comment: after you cast `nullptr` to whatever pointer type how is different from casting `NULL`, you got a new target type in both cases.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I haven't read the actual spec on this one, but I'm pretty sure that the call you indicated would be ambiguous without a cast, since a null pointer can be converted to a pointer of any type.  So the cast should be necessary.

And no, unfortunately, `nullptr` is not a template.  I really like that idea, though, so you could consider writing a function like this one:

```
template <typename PtrType> PtrType null() {
     return static_cast<PtrType>(nullptr);
}
```

And then you could write

```
f(null<int*>());
```

Comment: You should be on the standards committee! That's clean, nice syntax....  Another 50 years and I'm sure it will be in there!

Comment: @Dov - I'm not that very impressed over the improvement from the old `f((int*)0);`. Guess that's what the committee considered.

Comment: @Bo Persson- I think the real advantage here is that, while you still have to cast a null pointer to the proper pointer type, there's no risk that you'll accidentally call a function overloaded on an integral type instead of a pointer type.  It also means that you can have a function that's explicitly overloaded on `nullptr_t`, which does actually seem to have some uses.

Comment: Frankly, null is much more self documenting than 0, but if you have to cast it does lose some of its allure

Comment: @templatetypedef - I **am** impressed over `nullptr` and overloading on `nullptr_t`. It is just the utility of `null<int*>()` that wasn't overwhelming - sorry.  :-)

Comment: Personally I would make that `template<typename PtrType> PtrType* null() { return nullptr; }`, as it makes the usage slightly cleaner.